# Automation of email sending process through corporate webmail

Tags: ruby, smtp, sendmail, webmail

I am in need of a script which automatically sends particular data from my corporate webmail email id .

Till now I am able to send automatic emails from a gmail id. But Iam unable to configure it for my webmail id.

Please let me know if any configuration changes are needed or I need to setup a server for this.(if possible also help me how to configure the server)

This is the Ruby function which I am using

```
def send_mail(to_recepient,data,mailSubject,extraBodyText,sender_info)

    options = { :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
              :port                 => 587,
              :domain               => 'mail.gmail.com',
              :user_name            => sender_info[:senderName],
              :password             => sender_info[:senderPassword],
              :authentication       => 'plain',
              :enable_starttls_auto => true  }



  Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp, options
  end

  Mail.deliver do
         to "#{to_recepient}"
       from 'mailtest20152@gmail.com'
    subject mailSubject
      body stringData 

      fh=File.open('attachment_file',"w")

      fh.puts data
     add_file :filename => 'attachment_file', :content => data

  end

  File.unlink('attachment_file')
end
```

Comment: I think this is not a coding problem. f this works with gmail, it should also work with any other webmails that gives you smtp server to use. Just see in your webmail what's its configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar problem. You can configure mailer for particular smtp server like this:

```
options = { :address              => "smtp.yourdomain.com", #address can differ
          :port                 => 25  }
```

Don't forget to add:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Don't need to provide password and username, but remember to specify `from` field in your email message (as you already did).